# How to implement a counter function using firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I WANT TO IMPLEMENT A COUNTER FUNCTION USING FIREBASE FUNCTION TO COUNT NO OF TIMES MY APP IS BEING OPENED.

What I want:

Android app opened---> app calling ------>firebase function executed via http trigger------->firebase function increment value stored in firebase database

How to read and update data on firebase realtime database from firebase Functions.

I made an Firebase function which triggers on http triggers.

Code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.counterFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.send("Hello from Firebase");

******Code to increment value in firebase database*********

});
```

I have a field in firebase realtime database called count and 0 corresponds to it

```
count : 0
```

I want to increment count variable every time the firebase function is executed

IN SHORT I WANT TO IMPLEMENT A COUNTER USING FIREBASE.

I just want to record the number of times my app started . So I am calling the Http Trigger function using http request using 'okhttp' and the function need to increment the count.

Answer (score 0):

The following Firebase function example should help you understand how to write to the realtime database from a function

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/3b41b2e04d854a821a0149e1e5b0769bad397d67/quickstarts/uppercase

Have also a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: BTW, if your goal is only to "count the number of times your Android app is opened, you should maybe look at Google Analytics for Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = admin.initializeApp();

exports.counterFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase");

  return app.database().ref(`/count`).once('value', (snap) => {
    const value = snap.val() || 0;
    return app.database().ref(`/count`).set(value + 1).then(res => {
      return true;
    }).catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
  });
});
```

This will increment your counter each time your cloud function is executed.